# Cannot install homebrew on MacOS M1

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rvm, apple-m1

**When I run `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
It gives information listed:**

```
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R ron:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 3f4bcd7eb Merge pull request #10471 from MikeMcQuaid/formula-language-java
Traceback (most recent call last):
    22: from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `<main>'
    21: from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:31:in `require_relative'
    20: from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    18: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    17: from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    15: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    14: from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/duration.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/time.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle (LoadError)
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

**Tried a few ways but doesn't work. Did anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance.**

1. ruby --version: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580)
   [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
2. which ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
3. rvm current: system

Comment: I googled your error and [this was the top result](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/khpoxg/ruby_date_corebundle_not_working_with_m1/). Does that solve your problem, by any chance?

Comment: Nope, /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-3.3.0/lib/psych.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-3.3.0/lib/psych.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-3.3.0/lib/psych.bundle (LoadError)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally workaround. Use `brew cleanup` to fix the ruby.

Comment: I get the same error when I run `brew cleanup` 

Answer (score 0):

This was working for me - I had the same problems.

```
gem uninstall date
```

and same for io-console, etc, zlib, bigdecimal

and also I had problems with psych and strscan - for this libs i first had to delete the bundles:

```
rm /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/psych-3.3.0/psych.bundle
rm /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/psych-3.3.0/lib/psych.bundle
rm /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/strscan-3.0.0/lib/strscan.bundle
rm /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/strscan-3.0.0/strscan.bundle
```

before gem uninstall worked. After this homebrew install worked again like a charm.

with

```
gem update
```

I also get back again the problem, to take care

Comment: see also here: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/752#discussioncomment-359589